# Store a tree structure in HTML to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treeview, html-lists

I have a tree structure in HTML like the below:

```
<ul id="org" style="display:none">
  <li>
    Food
    <ul>
      <li>Beer</li>
      <li>Vegetables
        <ul>
          <li>Pumpkin</li>
          <li>Aubergine</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Bread</li>
      <li>Chocolate
        <ul>
          <li>Topdeck</li>
          <li>Reese's Cups</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am using [jOrgChart](https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart) from GitHub and you may see a [demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html) here.

I want to store this tree structure into my database and I have a table like below:

```
id | name | parent_id
```

However I just can't find a way to do that. Any one could help on that?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Send the data to your server and handle it.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thanks for your reply, but it is too general for me. I am new to  web development and I am not able to do the recursion to store the tree into db.